# How to get unique dataframe of 2 sets of data for unique timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two sets of data as showing below, I would like to get data frame as follows for unique timestamp where `Data1` and `Data2` are not the same length.

Expected output is for unique timestamps with delta time 1 min so the date could be combined with two values of these data.

```
Data1 =[10, 5, 20, 4, 30]
timestamps1 = ['2015-01-04 08:28:4',
                              '2015-01-04 08:37:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:41:07',
                             '2015-01-04 08:43:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:49:05']

Data2 = [1, 3, 7, 5]
timestamps2 = ['2015-01-04 08:28:3',
                              '2015-01-04 08:37:0',
                              '2015-01-04 08:40:0',
                              '2015-01-04 08:50:08']

Expected output format:
Timestamps       Data1      Data2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, is your expected output an empty data frame?\

Comment: No, it is the expected format that the output should have.

Comment: The "format" doesn't say anything. Please post the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this :

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

Data1 =[10, 5, 20, 4, 30]
timestamps1 = ['2015-01-04 08:28:04',
                              '2015-01-04 08:37:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:41:07',
                             '2015-01-04 08:43:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:49:05']

Data2 = [1, 3, 7, 5]
timestamps2 = ['2015-01-04 08:28:3',
                              '2015-01-04 08:37:0',
                              '2015-01-04 08:40:0',
                              '2015-01-04 08:50:08']

from datetime import datetime

df1 =  pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([timestamps1,Data1]).T,columns=["timestamp","Data1"])
df2 =  pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([timestamps2,Data2]).T,columns=["timestamp","Data2"])

df = pd.DataFrame([],columns=["timestamp","Data1","Data2"])

for i in range(min(len(timestamps1),len(timestamps2))) : 

  t1 = datetime.strptime(timestamps1[i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  df.loc[i,"timestamp"] = timestamps1[i]

  for j in range(len(timestamps2)) : 

    t2 = datetime.strptime(timestamps2[j], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    difference = t1 - t2

    if difference.total_seconds()/60 > 1 or difference.total_seconds()/60 < -1 : 
      df.loc[i,"Data1"] = df1.loc[i,"Data1"]
      df.loc[i,"Data2"] = df2.loc[i,"Data2"]
```

output :

```
   timestamp Data1 Data2
0  2015-01-04 08:28:04    10     1
1  2015-01-04 08:37:05     5     3
2  2015-01-04 08:41:07    20     7
3  2015-01-04 08:43:05     4     5
```

Comment: Thanks , but how i do unique time stamp for both data set

Comment: is the output i gave wrong ? please give me an idea about the output you want, can you write an example

Comment: i mean , the output without NaN , so compering between two time stamps if the Delta is with in 1 mints then this time stamp merge both data .. example

Comment: okay so you want the first time stamp to take the data of the closest next one

Comment: I update it my answer, i wish it helps, if it's not what you want i think it's close you can use it to do what you are looking for, you can tell that it's a hard work can you please upvote at least

Comment: Thanks Nassim ! .. i prefer to have as output                                               
  timestamp      Data1 Data2
4/01/2015 8:28 10          1
4/01/2015 8:37 5          3
4/01/2015 8:41 20          7
4/01/2015 8:43 4           7
4/01/2015 8:49 30           5